# How to construct a raw Ethereum transaction from transaction data

Tags: web3js, json-rpc, web3.py, raw-transaction, ethers.js

Let's say I have the following transaction information:

```json
{
  "jsonrpc":"2.0"
  "id":0
  "result":{
    "blockHash":"0x43dd926aa138a58d3f4740dae387bcff3c7bc525db2d0a449f323f8b8f92a229"
    "blockNumber":"0xa4f285"
    "from":"0xea8a7ef30f894bce23b42314613458d13f9d43ea"
    "gas":"0x30d40"
    "gasPrice":"0x2e90edd000"
    "hash":"0x72ee43a3784cc6749f64fad1ecf0bbd51a54dd6892ae0573f211566809e0d511"
    "input":"0x"
    "nonce":"0x1e7"
    "to":"0xbd064928cdd4fd67fb99917c880e6560978d7ca1"
    "transactionIndex":"0x0"
    "value":"0xde0b6b3a7640000"
    "v":"0x25"
    "r":"0x7e833413ead52b8c538001b12ab5a85bac88db0b34b61251bb0fc81573ca093f"
    "s":"0x49634f1e439e3760265888434a2f9782928362412030db1429458ddc9dcee995"
  }
}
```

Along with anything else you may need about the network broadly (such as `chain_id`).

Is it possible to construct an analogous raw transaction from this information without knowing the private key of the sender?

Feel free to use your favorite Web3 SDK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A raw transaction is just all the transaction parameters encoded in the [RLP](https://eth.wiki/fundamentals/rlp) format. A raw transaction consists of (in this order):

- Nonce;
- Gas price;
- Gas limit;
- To address;
- Value;
- Data.

You don't need the private key of the sender: to get the raw transaction, you can simply encode it using `RLP(Nonce, Gas Price, Gas limit, To, Value, Data)`. Here's an example implementation in JavaScript (using [ethereumjs/rlp](https://github.com/ethereumjs/rlp)):

```js
import { encode } from 'rlp';

const transaction = {
  nonce: '0x1e7',
  gasPrice: '0x2e90edd000',
  gasLimit: '0x30d40',
  to: '0xbd064928cdd4fd67fb99917c880e6560978d7ca1',
  value: '0xde0b6b3a7640000',
  data: '0x'
};

// Raw transaction as Buffer
const rawTransaction = encode([transaction.nonce, transaction.gasPrice, transaction.gasLimit, transaction.to, transaction.value, transaction.data]);
console.log(rawTransaction.toString('hex'));
```

This results in the following raw transaction:

```
ec8201e7852e90edd00083030d4094bd064928cdd4fd67fb99917c880e6560978d7ca1880de0b6b3a764000080
```

The only part where a private key is required, is to sign the transaction. A signed transaction is basically the raw transaction with the `v`, `r` and `s` signature (of the raw transaction) added to it: `RLP(Nonce, Gas Price, Gas limit, To, Value, Data, v, r, s)`. The chain ID is encoded in the `v` parameter (see [EIP-155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-155)).

Here's an example of how to sign the transaction and get the signed transaction:

```js
import { randomBytes } from 'crypto';
import { ecsign, keccak256 } from 'ethereumjs-util';
import { encode } from 'rlp';

// Randomly generated 32 byte private key
const privateKey = randomBytes(32);

const transaction = {
  nonce: '0x1e7',
  gasPrice: '0x2e90edd000',
  gasLimit: '0x30d40',
  to: '0xbd064928cdd4fd67fb99917c880e6560978d7ca1',
  value: '0xde0b6b3a7640000',
  data: '0x',
  chainId: 1
};

const params = [transaction.nonce, transaction.gasPrice, transaction.gasLimit, transaction.to, transaction.value, transaction.data];

// Raw transaction as Buffer
const rawTransaction = encode(params);
const hash = keccak256(rawTransaction);

// Signature of the hash of the raw transaction
const { v, r, s } = ecsign(hash, privateKey, transaction.chainId);

// RLP encoded signed transaction as Buffer
const signedTransaction = encode([...params, v, r, s]);
console.log(signedTransaction.toString('hex'));
```

Note the extra `chainId` property of `transaction`, this is required to get the correct value for `v`. If we assume our signature is the one mentioned in the example transaction, the signed transaction looks like this:

```
f86f8201e7852e90edd00083030d4094bd064928cdd4fd67fb99917c880e6560978d7ca1880de0b6b3a76400008025a07e833413ead52b8c538001b12ab5a85bac88db0b34b61251bb0fc81573ca093fa049634f1e439e3760265888434a2f9782928362412030db1429458ddc9dcee995
```

This is the full transaction that can be broadcast to the network. You can verify this through [MyCrypto's broadcast tool](https://mycrypto.com/pushTx) for example.

Comment: Nice! I think your code creates an unsigned transaction which cannot be directly sent to a network to replay the transaction. Can you include the signing step with v, r, s also please.

Comment: Correct, the raw transaction cannot be broadcast, since you need a valid signature to send a transaction. I updated the answer to include the signing.

Comment: @Morten From my understanding of the EIP-155, the `params` array should rather be `[transaction.nonce, transaction.gasPrice, transaction.gasLimit, transaction.to, transaction.value, transaction.data, transaction.chainId, 0, 0]`.