# Re-create raw transaction hash from transaction object

Tags: go-ethereum, python, rlp

Is there a way to re-create the signed transaction hash from tx object. I found the [How to construct a raw Ethereum transaction from transaction data](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87299/how-to-construct-a-raw-ethereum-transaction-from-transaction-data) answer helpful, but when I try to re-create the code in python using rlp.encode() I get a different value. For example using rawTransaction.hex() for unsigned transaction I get: f85b8530783165378c3078326539306564643030308730783330643430aa307862643036343932386364643466643637666239393931376338383065363536303937386437636131913078646530623662336137363430303030823078
instead of
ec8201e7852e90edd00083030d4094bd064928cdd4fd67fb99917c880e6560978d7ca1880de0b6b3a764000080